# Assigning max value + 1 to a column

Tags: sql-server

I need something like this pseudo code;

```
UPDATE  Orders
SET     InvoiceNo = MAX(InvoiceNo)
FROM    Orders INNER JOIN SetupAccountTypes ON Orders.AccountTypeID = SetupAccountTypes.ID
WHERE  (SetupAccountTypes.AccountType = N'COD') AND (Orders.DeliveryDate &gt;= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (Orders.DeliveryDate &lt;= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-01-31 00:00:00', 102))
```

That is, a bunch of rows selected under the given WHERE criteria get assigned invoice numbers incrementally.

How do I achieve this please in T-SQL or otherwise?

Thanks

Regards

Comment: Not sure what you want, show us sample data and expected result.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: We need a good answer on how to implement custom sequences in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear from the question but it looks like you are attempting to update a table based on the data from another table. One nice tool for SQL Server is the MERGE Statement.  [SQL MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

It will allow you to perform insert updates and deletes on a target table based on the results of a join with a source table.  (All in a single statement)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like some orders have invoices and some don't, since you are filtering the Order table on date. That suggests a slightly different solution: maybe you can more easily solve your problem with a table structure tweak instead of a complicated query. Instead of putting invoice number in the orders table, make a table for Invoices. If you use InvoiceNo as a Primary Key in that table, it will automatically increment the InvoiceNo for you - no manual query required.

```
CREATE TABLE Invoices 
(InvoiceNo bigint PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
 OrderId bigint REFERENCES ORDERS.OrderNo
);
```

This table uses your primary key from the Orders table (maybe you named it OrderNo, maybe something else) to tie Invoices to Orders.

You can use insert into select to populate this table:

```
INSERT INTO Invoices (OrderNo)
SELECT Orders.OrderNo
FROM    Orders INNER JOIN SetupAccountTypes ON Orders.AccountTypeID =     SetupAccountTypes.ID
WHERE  (SetupAccountTypes.AccountType = N'COD') AND (Orders.DeliveryDate &gt;= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (Orders.DeliveryDate &lt;= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-01-31 00:00:00', 102))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
declare @counter = (SELECT MAX(InvoiceNo) FROM Orders)

UPDATE  Orders
SET     InvoiceNo = @counter, @counter = @counter + 1
FROM    Orders 
INNER JOIN SetupAccountTypes 
    ON Orders.AccountTypeID = SetupAccountTypes.ID
WHERE  (SetupAccountTypes.AccountType = N'COD') 
    AND (Orders.DeliveryDate &gt;= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) 
    AND (Orders.DeliveryDate &lt;= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-01-31 00:00:00', 102))
```